# OpenTK redrawing while window is resized

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm writing a project using OpenTK as its graphics library.

When I resize an `OpenTK.GameWindow`, the frame doesn't update until the cursor is released. As a result, parts of the viewport are either clipped (when sizing smaller) or filled in with black (when sizing larger). I'm currently following the [learn OpenTK tutorial](https://opentk.net/learn/chapter1/index.html) and have completed drawing a triangle, having derived a new child class of `OpenTK.GameWindow`.

Here are some of the `OpenTK.GameWindow` events I've overridden with drawing logic:

```
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        GL.ClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);

        VertexBufferObject = GL.GenBuffer();
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VertexBufferObject);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vertices.Length * sizeof(float), vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

        shader = new Shader("Shaders\\shader.vert", "Shaders\\shader.frag");
        shader.Use();

        VertexArrayObject = GL.GenVertexArray();
        GL.BindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 3 * sizeof(float), 0);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VertexBufferObject);

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
    {
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
        GL.BindVertexArray(0);
        GL.UseProgram(0);

        GL.DeleteBuffer(VertexBufferObject);
        GL.DeleteBuffer(VertexArrayObject);

        shader.Dispose();
        base.OnUnload(e);
    }

    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

        shader.Use();
        GL.BindVertexArray(VertexArrayObject);
        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 3);

        Context.SwapBuffers();

        base.OnRenderFrame(e);
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        GL.Viewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
        base.OnResize(e);
    }
```

Should I be putting some logic in `OnUpdateFrame` to resolve this problem? It seems like `OnResize` doesn't trigger until the window is no longer being resized.

There seems to be [some information](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html) returned by google regarding this subject that I'm not sure how to follow up with:

> On some platforms, a window move, resize or menu operation will cause event processing to block. This is due to how event processing is designed on those platforms. You can use the window refresh callback to redraw the contents of your window when necessary during such operations.

Comment: "As a result, parts of the viewport are either clipped (when sizing smaller) or filled in with black (when sizing larger)." This is absolutely normal Window Behavior. Redrawing while drawing is a *very* bad idea. Redrawing is very expensive. And you would have to do it around once per each Pixel that is added/removed during resizing. | Also in games you usually do not drag the Window to get a Resolution. You pick a set of values from a Dropdown.

Comment: @Christopher: Why is it bad? A typical game will redraw at the monitor refresh rate, is the window going to change in size more often than that?

Comment: @Andrea If you do it once per pixel? You can *bet* it is more then teh refresh rate. How it works right now is entierly sufficient. Maybe he should disable dragging entirely and let the resolution be selectable from a Dropdown. Most games seem to do that. Especially those with Windowed Mode.

Comment: I assume you have some sort of render loop/callback that runs many times per second. You could log the new window size each time it changes, but only redraw when you normally do. That should be smooth_ish_

Comment: I think that even some convincing way to fake resizing would be fine in my usecase as well. I won't be drawing many objects, relatively speaking. So if there's a way to draw in some low LOD in the sections that would turn black, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
protected override void OnResize (ResizeEventArgs e)
{
     GL.Viewport (0, 0, Size.X, Size.Y);
     base.OnResize (e);
}
```

instead of

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
   GL.Viewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
   base.OnResize(e);
}
```

**OpenTK already has height and width values ​​assigned to its already created window**